# Python - How do I turn String into Array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a 2d array 
`[['s1.modernroleplay.net', '27016', '27015'], ['s2.modernroleplay.net', '27019', '27018'], ['s3.modernroleplay.net', '27022', '27021']]`

This 2d Array is stored in MySQL, once taking it out of MySQL it is in a String format.

How can I convert this string, back into an array?

Comment: A bit hacky: but `eval("[['s1.modernroleplay.net', '27016', '27015'], ['s2.modernroleplay.net', '27019', '27018'], ['s3.modernroleplay.net', '27022', '27021']]")` ; don't `eval` anything you can't verify, because it'll execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Before you go `eval`ing stuff, I'd first consider `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast`

for example:

```
import ast

print(ast.literal_eval("[['s1.modernroleplay.net', '27016', '27015'], ['s2.modernroleplay.net', '27019', '27018'], ['s3.modernroleplay.net', '27022', '27021']]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import json

my_string = "[['s1.modernroleplay.net', '27016', '27015'], ['s2.modernroleplay.net', '27019', '27018'], ['s3.modernroleplay.net', '27022', '27021']]".replace("'", '"')

my_array = json.loads(f'{{"array" : {my_string}}}')['array']
print(my_array)

# output
# [['s1.modernroleplay.net', '27016', '27015'],
#  ['s2.modernroleplay.net', '27019', '27018'],
#  ['s3.modernroleplay.net', '27022', '27021']]
```